# Confirmation for $E(X) = \int_0^b(1-F(x)) \ dx$ where $F(x)$ denotes CDF of random variable X with range $[0, b]$.

Tags: calculus, integration, expected-value

I saw several proofs of $\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_0^\infty (1-F(x)) \ dx$ where $F(x)$ denotes CDF, the standard one looks like this:

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty (1-F(x)) \mathrm{d}x &= \int_0^\infty  \left[ \int_0^\infty f(t)\mathrm{d}t - F(x)  \right]\mathrm{d}x\newline
&= \int_0^\infty  \left[ \int_0^\infty f(t)\mathrm{d}t - \int_0^xf(t)\ \mathrm{d}t  \right] \mathrm{d}x\newline
&= \int_0^\infty  \int_x^\infty  f(t)\;\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}x\newline
&= \int_0^\infty  \int_0^t  f(t)\;\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}t\newline
&= \int_0^\infty  f(t)t\ \Big|_0^t\;\mathrm{d}t\newline
&= \int_0^\infty  f(t)t\;\mathrm{d}t\newline
&=\mathbb{E}[X].\square
\end{align}
$$

Using the same technique, I find that it's also true for any range of $X$ not just $[0, \infty)$. That is if X takes the value in the range $[0, b]$ for $b\in\mathbb{R}, b\gt 0$ then:

$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_0^b(1-F(x)) \ \mathrm{d}x.
$$

But I'm not sure if something mysteriously goes wrong when I change the limit of integration? If nothing wrong then I'm wondering why the formula has been generalized as such.

Comment: Notice that $1-F(t) = \mathbb P(X > t)$. In particular, if $X$ takes values in some range, you can quickly tell when this is $0$ or $1$. It also provides an explanation as to why integrating it gives the expected value, no?

Comment: @Pedro, It happened that I'd misinterpreted your comment above, can you elaborate more on this sentence "if $X$ takes values in some range, you can quickly tell when this is 0 or 1"?

Comment: And also I believe you mean $1-F(x)=\mathbb{P}(X>x)$.

Comment: If $X \leqslant b$ then $P(X>b)= 0$ so $1-F(t) = 0$ for $t>b$. Thus, you can replace the integral over $(0,\infty)$ to one over $(0,b)$. I think this is what you wanted to do.

Comment: @Pedro, thanks for your simple & straightforward explanation. With that I can also see why the formula didn't bother mentioning the case where right endpoint is a real number.